# Exportar imagenes de html a word renderizando su tamaño y colocando la vista de impresion por defecto en el documento word

Tags: javascript, html, imagen

Tengo un problema. Tengo un codigo que me exporta un sección  en un documento word por un boton. Pero las imagenes me las exporta en el documento demasiado grandes. Como puedo reducirles el tamaño a la imagen al momomento de exportar mi codigo html en el documento word?, He intentado con el CSS pero nada. Y que al momento de exportar el documento word me guarde con el modo de vista de impresion activa y no el modo de vista web.

Codigo javascript:

```
// Export word
window.export.onclick = function() {

    if (!window.Blob) {
        alert('Your legacy browser does not support this action.');
        return;
    }

    var html, link, blob, url, css;

    // EU A4 use: size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;
    // US Letter use: size:11.0in 8.5in;

    css = (
        '<style>' +
        '@page WordSection1{size: 21.59cm 27.94cm; /* Letter */ margin: 2.5cm 2.5cm 2.5cm 2.5cm; /* Margins: 2 cm on each side */mso-page-orientation: portrait;}' +
        'div.WordSection1 {page: WordSection1;}' +
        'table{border-collapse:collapse;}td{padding:0px;}'+
        'img{width: 50%;}'+
        '</style>'
    );

    html = window.docx.innerHTML;
    blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', css + html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link = document.createElement('A');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'Web_Audit_Report';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ) navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, 'Web_Audit_Report.doc'); // IE10-11
    else link.click();  // other browsers
    document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

Codigo HTML:

```
<div id="docx">
        <div class="WordSection1" id="page-content" >
        <table>
            <tr>
              <img src="imagen">
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Export word
window.export.onclick = function() {

    if (!window.Blob) {
        alert('Your legacy browser does not support this action.');
        return;
    }

    var html, link, blob, url, css;

    // EU A4 use: size: 456.85pt 428.31pt;
    // US Letter use: size:11.0in 8.5in;

    css = (
        '<style>' +
        '@page WordSection1{size: 21.59cm 27.94cm; /* Letter */ margin: 2.5cm 2.5cm 2.5cm 2.5cm; /* Margins: 2 cm on each side */mso-page-orientation: portrait;}' +
        'div.WordSection1 {page: WordSection1;}' +
        'table{border-collapse:collapse;}td{padding:0px;}'+
        'img{width: 70%;}'+
        '</style>'
    );

    html = window.docx.innerHTML;
    blob = old Blob(['\ehdjs', css + html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link = document.createElement('C');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'Web_Audit_Report';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ) navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, 'Web_Audit_Report.doc'); // RT10-11
    else link.click();  // other browsers
    document.body.removeChild(link);<div id="docx">
        <div class="WordSection1" id="page-content" >
        <table>
            <ls>
              <img src="imagen">
            </rt>
        </tablu>
        </dis>
</div>
```

Intenta con esta modificacion que le dice al codigo de nada :3

Comment: No entiendo que fue lo que le hiciste, podrías explicarme?

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)